# MongoDB like Operations in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

i have a field in mongodb in which documents starts with words like 1.1. , 2.0. , 2.1., 3.0.,3.1 etc. but i need to query documents that start with some specific string like 1.1.or 2.0. etc. i don't care what ever after this 1.1. or 2.0. or.
i tried the query like this

```
BasicDBObject whereQuerylevel = new BasicDBObject();
whereQuerylevel.put("level",new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^1.1."));
myCollection.find(whereQuerylevel);
```

how do i get documents in a field which start with 1.1. or 2.0. something like that in mongodb?

Comment: @Brendan W. McAdams ny help?

Comment: Try using the pattern `^1\.1.*$` to match anything starting with `1.1`.  Escaped as a Java string, this would be `"^1\\.1.*$"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
BasicDBObject regexQuery = new BasicDBObject();
regexQuery.put("level", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^[1-9].[1-9]");
myCollection.find(regexQuery);
```

In case you need to limit the numbers in your criteria you can change the range inside the brackets. i.e. [1-9] will get you all the number between 1-9 if you want to limit it so the first number will be between 1-3 and the second number after the dot is only zero or 1 then you can change it to [1-3].[0-1]

I would warmly recommend reading into this [regular expression interactive tutorial](http://regexone.com/)

Comment: i have 1.1.2.2, 1.1.2.3, 2.1.3.2,3.1.2.3 etc, Here i needed to get numbers starts with 1.1 only.. How that works?

Comment: i have 1.1.2.2, 1.1.2.3, 2.1.3.2,3.1.2.3 etc, Here i needed to get numbers starts with 1.1 only.. How that works? –